# Programmatically set Drupal 7 custom date field?

Tags: drupal-7

I have a custom profile field "**field_date_observed**" which has format "2014-10-21". I am trying to set its value using the code further down but am getting the error:

```
EntityMetadataWrapperException: Invalid data value given. Be sure it matches the required data type and format. in EntityMetadataWrapper->set()
```

The code:

```
$todays_date = date('Y-m-d');
$uid=23;
$obj_container = user_load($uid);
$obj = entity_metadata_wrapper('user', $obj_container);
$obj->field_date_observed = $todays_date;
$obj->save();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use UNIX timestamp format to set the date value with entity_medata_wrapper.

Try changing the first line to:

```
$todays_date = strtotime(date('Y-m-d'));
```